# What do the Delete Team Projects dialog choices mean?

Tags: tfs

I've copied a folder from one Team Project to another one, and now I want to delete the original Team Project, but I want to make sure I keep my history.  When I try to delete the original project, I get this dialog box:

[image]

What do these choices mean, and what should I check to make sure that I keep history on the moved folder?  **Will** my history be preserved if I delete the original?  There seems to be much confusion online about this question.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say you copied a folder?  If you truly mean copy, then there should be no history for those files.  Copy shows up in TFS as creating new folders/files.

If you *moved* the folder, then there is a link back to the history in the original team project, and deleting that team project will remove that portion of the history.

If this is a concern then you don't necessarily have to delete the old team project.  If you just remove everybodies access it will no longer show up in the list, but the data is still around if you ever need it.